# Unable to import Client from node-pg

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I am trying to use Postgresql in a Node project. I am using modular imports, so I am having issues importing 'pg':

```
import * as pg from 'pg'
const { Client } = pg
let client = new Client()
```

leading to this error

```
        let client = new Client()
                     ^
TypeError: Client is not a constructor
```

I've looked at a couple other questions similar to this, but still have issues:

```
import { native as pg } from 'pg';
let client = new pg.Client()
```

leading to this error:

```
import { native as pg } from 'pg';
         ^^^^^^
    SyntaxError: Named export 'native' not found. The requested module 'pg' is a CommonJS module, which may not support all module.exports as named exports.
```

Does anyone know what I can try to make this import correctly?

Comment: From the error suggestion, just need to change it to `import pg from 'pg'`, you code should be able to run.

Comment: wow, this works! can you add that as an answer to resolve this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the error suggestion, pg is a CommonModule which may not support all module.exports as named exports.

change the import from

```
import * as pg from 'pg'
```

to

```
import pg from 'pg'
```

will solve the import problem.

Answer (score 1):

for me it worked as below:

import pg from "pg";

const client = new pg.Client({